# Can I safely store mac and windows backups on an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: ext4, time-machine

I want to store time machine backups on a storage server running ubuntu server with an ext4 filesystem.  If I only ever interact with the server over the network, will I be able to safely recover this mac backup?

Can I safely store my windows backups there as well?  What utility is recommended to snapshot a windows box?

Answer (score 1):

It is *mostly* safe to backup a Windows/MacOS box to a Linux host, but you need to consider the following factors:

1. for data (ie: file content), there is not problem
2. for ACL metadata, you need to copy files using an utility capable of not only read/write ACLs, but also to store them in EXT4 format
3. regarding the Windows box, if alternate data stream are present **and** they need to be copied as well, you are out of luck, as EXT4 (nor any other Linux filesystem, for what I know) does not support them

All considered, I am extremely satisfied using [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) + [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) combo. Using them, you can schedule automated, deduplicated (via hardlinks) backups. Using the right options (`-AX`), rsync is even capable of storing ACLs. For the MacOS box, you will find native rsync support. For the Windows box, you can install it via [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)